# Extending Protocols conforming to NSFetchRequestResult

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, protocols, swift3

I am migrating my code to Swift 3 and I ran into an issue that I am not 100% sure about.

As of WWDC 2016 the Core Data team updated their framework to be friendlier to generics and the new beefed up `NSFetchRequest` now returns objects that conform to the `NSFetchRequestResult`.

So in the code below I have my base protocol that conforms to the said `NSFetchRequestResult` protocol, and in an extension of its child protocol `ManagedObjectFetchable` I want to return fetch objects of conforming types:

```
import CoreData

@objc protocol ManagedObjectType: class, NSFetchRequestResult { }

protocol ManagedObjectFetchable: ManagedObjectType { }

extension ManagedObjectFetchable {
  static func preFetch(for predicate: Predicate, sortedBy sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor]) throws -> [Self] {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Self>(entityName: Self.entityName)
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors

    let dummyContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    return try dummyContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
  }
}
```

The problem here is this line:

```
// Error: Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'NSFetchRequest<_>.Type' and 'Self.Type'
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Self>(entityName: Self.entityName)
```

It is a little confusing because I don't think this has anything to do with binary operators... Before I jump to the all too easy conclusion that it is a Swift bug I was wondering if anyone ran into similar issues.

---

I am able to get around this using generics:

```
extension ManagedObjectFetchable {
  static func preFetch<T: ManagedObjectFetchable>(for predicate: Predicate, sortedBy sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor]) throws -> [T] {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<T>(entityName: Self.entityName)
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors

    let dummyContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    return try dummyContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
  }
}
```

This is what I am going with for now but I don't like not understanding why this would not work. If anyone could help enlighten this problem that would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Swift. Change:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Self>(entityName: Self.entityName)
```

to:

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Self> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: Self.entityName)
```

and the code should compile.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks Jack, I didn't think of trying that workaround. I filed a radar for this: https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6083573912174592